# Python win32com.client and outlook

Tags: python, win32com

I am trying to iterate over my email box and find an email with a specific subject. I am using:

```
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case,
                                    # the inbox. You can change that number to reference
                                    # any other folder
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetLast()
print(message)
body_content = message.body
print body_content
```

Does anyone know where I can find documentation for this. I would like to use a GetAll() function then filter by subject, or a getSubject() function, but I can't find documentation on this at all. Any help would be great.

Comment: Python very good self documentation will not help you here. Go for the documentation of COM object you are using, they usually have nice looking help files about that.

Comment: where would I find that? I have looked no luck

Comment: what about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765775(v=office.15).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found that a google search for "microsoft interop  " leads me very quickly to the right set of pages. In your case I did "microsoft interop outlook getdefaultfolder" which led me to MSDN's [NameSpaceClass.GetDefaultFolder Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.namespaceclass.getdefaultfolder%28v=office.14%29.aspx) page which led me (after a few clicks) to the [Items Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.items_members%28v=office.14%29.aspx) page.

I use the same search technique for all MS Office apps.